Что делает Bitmap.LockBits если параметр format и параметр bitmapData.PixelFormat различны?
Что делает Bitmap.LockBits если параметр format и параметр bitmapData.PixelFormat различны?
bitmap.LockBits(
   rect,
   ImageLockMode.ReadOnly | ImageLockMode.UserInputBuffer,
   format,
   bitmapData
);


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
